# Actualizar Input apartir de Select con base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, select

Buenos dias tengo la siguiente duda...

Tengo un **select** con varias opciones a partir de una **base de datos**, quiero actualizar un input en el mismo formulario con un valor **"1"** ya lo logre hacer con las opciones en especifico que le puse, el problema ahora es que necesito que cuando no sean las opciones me regrese el valor a **"0"** ya que el input deja el valor de **"1"**, tengo el **codigo de la siguiente manera**.

```
var causa = {
  "Buffer lleno": ["1"],
  "Mala Programacion PC&L": ["1"],
  "No Programacion": ["1"],
  "Situacion Ambientales": ["1"],
  "TLO Planeado por PC&L": ["1"],
  "Validacion de modelo Planeado": ["1"],
  "Nuevo Modelo no Planeado": ["1"],
  "Nuevo Modelo Planeado": ["1"],
  "Mantenimiento Correctivo Planeado": ["1"],
  "Mantenimiento Preventivo (Limpieza)": ["1"],
  "Mantenimiento Preventivo Programado": ["1"],
  "Servicio No Planeado": ["1"],
  "Servicio Planeado": ["1"],
  "Junta con el Personal": ["1"],
  "Situacion de Riesgo": ["1"],
}

function cambioOpcionesStatus(){
  var combo = document.getElementById('causa');
  var opcion = combo.value;

  document.getElementById('StatusDwtp').value = causa[opcion][0];
}
```

**Codigo del select:**

```
<label>Causa Tiempo Perdido</label>
                        <select name="causa" id="causa" class="form-control" onchange='cambioOpcionesStatus();' required>
                        <option value disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
                        <?php
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                             $group[$row['categoria']][] = $row;
                        }
                         foreach ($group as $key => $values){
                             echo '<optgroup label="'.$key.'">';
                             foreach ($values as $value) 
                             {
                                 echo '<option name="'.$value['descripcion'].'" value="'.$value['descripcion'].'">'.$value['descripcion'].'</option>';
                             }
                             echo '</optgroup>';
                         }
                        } else {}
                        ?>
                        </select>
```

**El codigo del input:**

```
<input type="text" name="StatusDwtp" value="0" id="StatusDwtp" class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta, sobre todo esta parte: *«ahora es que necesito que cuando no sean las opciones me regrese el valor a "0" »*, ¿cuando no sean las opciones, qué opciones?

Comment: @A.Cedano Cualquier otra opcion que no sea de las que estan en mi codigo definidas en la var "causa", por que hay mas..

Comment: O sea, el `input` debe ponerse en `0` si el valor de alguna `option` seleccionada no se encuentra entre los valores de `causa`, ¿es correcto?

Comment: Asi es... encontre una manera que es declarando todas las otras opciones que existen, pero pues es mucho codigo, si no encuentro otra manera creo que lo dejare asi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esto lo puedes resolver.

Aquí se verifica si el `value` de `option` se encuentra en `causa`, en cuyo caso el `input` recibirá el valor `1`y si no está recibirá el valor `0`.

```js
var causa = {
  "Buffer lleno": ["1"],
  "Mala Programacion PC&L": ["1"],
  "No Programacion": ["1"],
  "Situacion Ambientales": ["1"],
  "TLO Planeado por PC&L": ["1"],
  "Validacion de modelo Planeado": ["1"],
  "Nuevo Modelo no Planeado": ["1"],
  "Nuevo Modelo Planeado": ["1"],
  "Mantenimiento Correctivo Planeado": ["1"],
  "Mantenimiento Preventivo (Limpieza)": ["1"],
  "Mantenimiento Preventivo Programado": ["1"],
  "Servicio No Planeado": ["1"],
  "Servicio Planeado": ["1"],
  "Junta con el Personal": ["1"],
  "Situacion de Riesgo": ["1"],
};

var combo = document.getElementById('causa');
var input = document.getElementById('StatusDwtp');


function cambioOpcionesStatus() {
  var opcion = combo.value;
  //Verificamos si opcion se encuentra en causa
  var inputValue = (opcion in causa) ? 1 : 0;
  input.value = inputValue;
}
```

```html
<select name="causa" id="causa" class="form-control" onchange='cambioOpcionesStatus();' required>
  <optgroup label="test">'
    <option value disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
    <option name="n1" value="Este no">Este no</option>';
    <option name="n2" value="Buffer lleno">Buffer lleno</option>';
    <option name="n3" value="Mala Programacion PC&L">Mala Programacion PC&L</option>';
    <option name="n4" value="Este tampoco">Este tampoco</option>';
    <option name="n5" value="Nuevo Modelo no Planeado">Nuevo Modelo no Planeado</option>';
  </optgroup>
</select>

<input type="text" name="StatusDwtp" value="0" id="StatusDwtp" class="form-control" />
```

## Recomendaciones

1. Verás que que he puesto la referencia a los elementos fuera de la función. De ese modo no se invoca al DOM cada vez que se llame a la función para obtener el `id` del elemento
2. Conviene evitar las funciones *in line*, es mejor escuchar los cambios del `select` desde Javascript, usando su id, y quitarle el atributo `onchange`. Así el código será menos dependiente del HTML, más portable y más fácil de mantener.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y las recomendaciones.